# Generating random uint256 numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, random

I need to generate a uint256 random number offchain (in a Node.js client). Since `BN` doesn't have a `random()` function, what's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Node.js' `crypto.randomBytes` to generate a cryptographically secure random number:

```js
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto';
import BN from 'bn.js';

const value = randomBytes(32); // 32 bytes = 256 bits

// Value as native bigint
const bigInt = BigInt(`0x${value.toString('hex')}`);

// Value as BN.js number
const bn = new BN(value.toString('hex'), 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have web3 you can use [randomHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#randomhex) from web3-utils.

```
web3.utils.randomHex(32)
> "0xa5b9d60f32436310afebcfda832817a68921beb782fabf7915cc0460b443116a"
```

Comment: And then use [`web3.utils.toBN()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-utils.html#tobn) to convert it to a `BN`, if needed.