# Random BigNumber in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, bignumber, random

I'm looking to generate a random [ethers.js BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber) in a certain range. While [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86880/generating-random-uint256-numbers-in-js) question has answers about random number generation, the answers as of this writing (April 2021) only cover BigInt, BN.js, and web3.js, and in addition, does not discuss ranges.

My primary use for this is generating random token amounts during tests. Tokens traditionally have a large amount of decimal places, making Big Number libraries necessary.

I've tried adopting the answers there, but cannot get them to work ethers, even before addressing the issue of creating a min/max range. For example, I tried:

```js
const randBytes = randomBytes(16); // from the node.js crypto library
const amount = BigNumber.from(`0x${randBytes.toString()}`);
```

or in place of the second line:

```js
const amount = BigNumber.from(`0x${new BN(randBytesMint.toString('hex'), 16)}`);
```

which give me:

````
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.13)```
````

Since in my personal case I do not need security guarantees, I'm also open to a solution using `Math.random()` and then scaling up using `ethers.utils.parseUnits()`, though secure random number answers are certainly appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only answers a non-secure generation (using `Math.random()`). If, for example, you want a random token value for a token with 18 decimal places that ranges between 1000 and 0.0001 of the token, you can use:

```js
const randNum = Math.random() * 100000;
const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(randNum.toString(), 18);
```

The first line generates a number between 1 and 100 thousand (6 zeroes). The second multiplies it by `1e18` (1 with 18 zeroes), meaning the number of tokens will will range up to 100,000, with decimal values a number of places after the decimal point (as to say, not only whole numbers).

Answer (score 8):

To generate a number in the entire uint256 range

```
ethers.BigNumber.from(ethers.utils.randomBytes(32))
```

You can add function wrappers around that if you need it in a certain range such as

```
function randomBN(max) {
  return ethers.BigNumber.from(ethers.utils.randomBytes(32)).mod(max);
}
```